# How to bind Rest API made from R to a dotnet application?

Tags: .net, iis, rstudio, plumber

I have created an Rest API from R with plumber package which gives an prediction for the received input, and we have developed User interface(UI) in  dotnet , please help me understanding the possible ways for integrating both

Comment: The common approach in this case would be to use something like [restasharp](http://restsharp.org) (or any other tool you like) to call endpoints of your API from your dotnet application.

Comment: Thankyou Mr.Oleh Formaniuk , I will give a try for it, but i have an other doubt.. i know its very silly,  when publishing an R api  from .net application, do we have to bind both dotnet and Rapi in the IIS, or should i keep the server on all the time. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understand what you are trying to build. How I see what you are trying to achieve: UI part done in dotnet as web application (MVC or whatever) and R application that exposes RESTful API to process requests from UI. If my guess is correct then you could think about this two services as separate parts. You can host R API in the way you like, preferably hidden from the external world so that it could be accessible only from your dotnet app via network.

Comment: Yes exactly i am doing my UI in dotnet, and exposing API'S with R,  When i am testing this from System this connection is working.. but when i deploy the UI in server ..  I couldn't see any communication between R & dotnet ... are there any specific requirements that i need to do when i productionize it.